# What design pattern can I use to complete a several steps process?

Tags: android, algorithm, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I'm developing an Android application and it requires a several steps registration process. Because the amount of data I need to collect is big I have create one activity and a different fragment for each step. For example in the first step/fragment the user has to provide basic information (name, gender, email), in the second step/fragment education information (university, degree, dates attended) and in the final step/fragment experience information (companies, title, dates).  As soon as the user completes correctly all steps, I send all the information in a single JSON request to my web service.

My question is: what would be the design or design pattern that better models this problem in an elegant, readable and testable way?. The approach I currently use, which I consider is not good at all and potentially can create memory leaks in the app is this:

```
    class Registration {

        // Contains basic user information such as name, gender, etc
        private User user; 

        // Each Education instance contains info such as university, degree, etc 
        private List<Education> studies; 

        // Each Experience instance contains info such as company name, title, etc
        private List<Experience> workExperience;

        private static Registration currentRegistration;

        public static Registration getCurrent() {
            if (currentRegistration == null) {
                currentRegistration = new Registration();
            }
            return currentRegistration;
        }

        /* There are getter and setter methods for each field */
    }
```

As you can see I have created the Registration class with the required fields and a static reference instance that represents the current registration which is provided through the getCurrent method to each fragment which call it from its onCreate method and set information of that step thought the corresponding setter method. When the user has entered all data I convert this POJO into JSON and make the network request.

Another approach could be to pass the Registration instance from fragment A to B for which I'd need to implement the serializable interface but I do not like this approach.

The Builder and JavaBean patterns have come to my mind but I see them more appropriate when I have to initiliase the object in a single block statements. Any recommendation about how can I model this problem properly? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating a very simple thing.

I have done this type of implementations before, it's actually fairly common as far as registration implementations go. I'm not sure if there are better options out there, I have seen quite a few different ones, but they all fail when it comes to simplicity, compared to how I typically do it:

1. Extend a Viewgroup of choice -  Typically a scrollview - create an xml layout and inflate it into your custom viewgroup.
2. On said xml add a different viewgroup containing each registration step, and set the visibility to gone.
3. On each registration page add a button to go to the next one.
4. On your custom viewgroup make sure you deal with the "next" button by validating the data first.
5. When the user reaches the end of the registration steps you can simply retrieve all it's data from the appropriate fields (i.e. passwordView.getText().toString()), and you can do this with confidence that you will not get any null pointers or surprises as you have been validating all data throughout the different steps.
6. Bonus points if you add page change view animations.

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: @jvrodriguez first of all thanks for your answer but I can not use that approach. What I described it's a very simplistic abstraction of what my real problem is and I used it just to make my problem understandable. I think that implementing a solution like yours forces me to have a _god object_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) with a lot of responsabilities. I like to create functional and unit tests for each feature, and having all logic inside a single class would be a mess.

Comment: Well by definition a god object is an object that performs too many tasks, this only performs one, it may be a lengthy one, but still only one. Either way I agree that I might have underestimated the amount of data that you require from your users. That being said I would suggest implementing http://bit.ly/1hZQWAh to communicate back to the activity after each fragment and build the object gradually.